# Is coldfusion 8 app server compatible with apache 2.4.10 web server

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

We are doing Migration from iPlanet web server to Apache 2.4.10 and We have successfully installed apache in this path: `/usr/local/opt/apache/`. When we try to configure Apache with ColdFusion 8 with the command,`/appl/ColdFusion8/runtime/bin->./wsconfig -ws Apache -dir /usr/local/opt/apache/conf -v`. We are getting some errors so coldfusion 8 not fully installed properly. So is coldfusion 8 compatible with apache 2.4.10?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a server admin question, so better fit for Server Fault.

Answer (score 3):

Apache 2.4 support only came to ColdFusion in version 10 ([ref](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/updates-for-coldfusion-11-coldfusion-10-and-coldfusion-9-released)). ColdFusion 8 has been out of support / EOL since 2012 ([ref](https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/eol/eol_matrix.html#63)).

The support matrix for ColdFusion 8 specifies Apache support only to 2.2 ([ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20080513154849/http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf8_systemsupportmatrix.pdf)).

NB: it only took about 5min to google all that. I can't help but think you could probably have done that yourself.

Comment: Note: ColdFusion 10/11 support for Apache 2.4.x only extends as far as 2.4.9 currently (see first ref - question asked but no reply. I made other enquiries with Adobe and was want told 2.4.10 not currently supported).

Comment: It'd be helpful if the downvoter explained why. I could poss. improve the answer..?